# How can we select input element in div using this keyword

Tags: jquery, this, selector

The below HTML code is generated from PHP and I want to select input elements and make them visible. As HTML Code is recurring, I want to use `this` keyword and select input elements.

I have tried to use the `parent` method in jquery but not able to concat the parent class name as selector. Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
  var x = $(this).parent();
  $(x + '.username').show(); // it is showing error
  $("this .password").show();
  $("this .email").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">ajay aaa asss@s.ock
  <span class="delete" data-id="30">delete</span>
  <span class="edit" data-id="30">edit</span>
  <input type="text" style="display:none" class="username">
  <input type="text" class="password" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" class="email" style="display:none">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('.selector', parent)` to select children with jQuery as followings

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
  var x = $(this).parent();
  $('.username', x).show();
  $(".password", x).show();
  $(".email", x).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">ajay aaa asss@s.ock
  <span class="delete" data-id="30">delete</span>
  <span class="edit" data-id="30">edit</span>
  <input type="text" style="display:none" class="username">
  <input type="text" class="password" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" class="email" style="display:none">

</div>
```

Comment: An alternative/equivalent  once you have `x` (in code above) is to use `x.find(".username).show()` - mostly as a matter of preference

Comment: @freedomn-m You're right. Actually `$('.selector', parent)` is internally converted to `$(parent).find('.selector')` which means the second one is probably faster.